# making a search items at the same line with a pagination nav

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I make the following search bar and its button at left of a page and the pagination  at right, at the same line, please ?

Here is the template that I'm working on : http://jsfiddle.net/ht97t/1/

```
<form role="search" method="get" action="/Accueil/Rechercher">
    <div class="col-xs-8">
        <input type="text" name="rech" class="form-control" placeholder="Rechercher">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button><br />
    <label style="margin-left:20px;"><input type="radio" name="type" value="nomPoste" /> Nom du poste de travail</label><label style="margin-left:12px;"><input type="radio" name="type" value="nomAppMetier" checked /> Nom de l'application métier</label>
</form>
<ul class="pagination pagination-sm" style="float:right;">
        <li class="disabled"><a href="#">&laquo;</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="#">1 <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">2 </a></li>
        <li><a href="#">3 </a></li>
        <li><a href="#">4 </a></li>
        <li><a href="#">5 </a></li>
        <li><a href="#">&raquo;</a></li>
</ul>
```

I've tried this, but, this haven't work : http://jsfiddle.net/ht97t/2/

**Note :** I'm using bootstrap.

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution for this is to make the `.pagination` absolute and move it accordingly.

**[Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ht97t/4/)**

CSS:

```
body {position: relative;}

.pagination {
 position: absolute;
 right: 0px;
 top: 0px;
 margin: 5px 0;
}
```

In this case I set the `body` to have `position:relative;` but you probably would want to switch that to the closest containing element.

Comment: @user3212730, yes in this situation you would probably need to add a containing div for the search bar and pagination nav. See this [http://jsfiddle.net/ht97t/8/](http://jsfiddle.net/ht97t/8/) example. In this example you can put content above or below the .search-nav-container.

Answer (score 2):

From the the bootstrap CSS;

```
.pagination {
    border-radius: 4px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 20px 0;
    padding-left: 0;
}
```

You will need to override that margin, for now just set an inline style on your UL to confirm;

```
<ul class="pagination pagination-sm" style="float:right; margin: 0!important;">
```

**Edit**

You should use the Bootstrap grid as documented (http://getbootstrap.com/css/), that is to define a row and then to specify the placement of content within that row by setting div classes.

For example if you wanted to have a search box top left and a pagination control top right of a row then try this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-8"><!--search here --></div>
  <div class="col-xs-4"><!--pagination here --></div>
</div>
```

If you want to leave some space between the left and right content then use the offset class:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6"><!--search here --></div>
  <div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-2"><!--pagination here --></div>
</div>
```

In your original example you had a Search Box left, Radio buttons middle and Pagination right, so you might just be best to go with a 4 4 4 grid:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-4"><!--search here --></div>
  <div class="col-xs-4"><!--radio buttons here --></div>
  <div class="col-xs-4"><!--pagination here --></div>
</div>
```

Comment: look, here is a survey of your solution : http://jsfiddle.net/ht97t/7/ sorry but this doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: here is a jsfiddle where all I have done is add inline css margin: 0 to your original jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/cbWQ5/

Answer (score 0):

You have several options to do this.

The quickest fix would be just to do a margin top of like 18px

```
   <form role="search" method="get" action="/Accueil/Rechercher">
        <span style="float:left; margin:18px 0 0 10px;">
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ht97t/3/  , 18px might not be perfect, but adjust accordingly

Comment: I'm trying to keep the same width of the search bar and not to become smaller ^^